# Index out of range error while using picker view

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I populated a picker view with different arrays, depending on which textfield you click on. However, whenever I choose the fifth row of the "Untergrund" Array the app crashes with the index out of range error. It shows me that row int = 4 and component int = 0. The error occurs in the line where the first if statement is set in the did select row function. I have no idea why this is happening ...

Here is the relevant code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var Stadt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Strasse: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Platzart: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Groesse: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var AnzToreKoerbe: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Untergrund: UITextField!

// Variable für die Firebase Database

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Stadt.delegate = self
    Untergrund.delegate = self
    Groesse.delegate = self
    AnzToreKoerbe.delegate = self
    Platzart.delegate = self
    Picker.delegate = self
}

@IBOutlet weak var Picker: UIPickerView!

var currentData = [""]

let UntergrundArray = ["Asphalt", "Kunstrasen Sand", "Kunstrasen Granulat", "Rasen", "Tartan", " "]
let StadtArray = ["Norderstedt", "Hamburg", "Berlin", "München"]
let GroesseArray = [ "2 vs 2", "3 vs 3", "4 vs 4", "5 vs 5"]
let AnzTorKoerbe = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
let Art = ["Fußball", "Basketball"]

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
    if textField.tag == 1{
        currentData = StadtArray
    }else if textField.tag == 2{
        currentData = UntergrundArray
    }else if textField.tag == 3 {
        currentData = GroesseArray
    }else if textField.tag == 4 {
        currentData = AnzTorKoerbe
    }else if textField.tag == 5 {
        currentData = Art

    }

    Picker.reloadAllComponents()

    return false;
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return currentData.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return currentData[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let itemSelected = currentData[row]

    print(itemSelected)

    if (itemSelected == StadtArray[row]) {
        Stadt.text = StadtArray[row]
    }else if (itemSelected == UntergrundArray[row]) {
        Untergrund.text = UntergrundArray[row]
    }else if (itemSelected == GroesseArray[row]) {
        Groesse.text = GroesseArray[row]
    }else if (itemSelected == AnzTorKoerbe[row]) {
        AnzToreKoerbe.text = AnzTorKoerbe[row]
    }else {
        Platzart.text = Art[row]
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are swapping the current model into `currentData` so that the correct count is always `currentData.count`, what is the point of the big `if/else` in `didSelectRow`? Surely `currentData[row]` is always the desired datum. And that way there can be no risk of getting the wrong model array and the wrong index value.

Comment: FYI - it is standard practice to name variables and methods to start with lowercase letters. Class names should start with uppercase letters.

Comment: @rmaddy Agreed, but understand that this is a difficult convention for German speakers, whose language _requires_ nouns to start with a capital letter. His variable names simply _are_ German words and look completely natural if you know German.

Comment: @matt, I hadn't thought about that. You're right, Swift variable naming is going to feel very unnatural to German speakers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`currentData` can be any one of the other arrays. And `row` can be for an index larger than some of the arrays. This is the cause of the crash.

The proper solution is to fix how you determine which label to update.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let itemSelected = currentData[row]

    if currentData === StadtArray {
        Stadt.text = itemSelected
    } else if currentData === UntergrundArray {
        Untergrund.text = itemSelected
    } else ... and the others as needed
}
```

Though a better option might be to add another property to track the current text field.

```
var currentField: UITextField?
```

Then update `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
    currentField = textField
    if textField.tag == 1 {
        currentData = StadtArray
    } else if textField.tag == 2 {
        currentData = UntergrundArray
    } else if textField.tag == 3 {
        currentData = GroesseArray
    } else if textField.tag == 4 {
        currentData = AnzTorKoerbe
    } else if textField.tag == 5 {
        currentData = Art
    }

    Picker.reloadAllComponents()

    return false;
}
```

Then update `didSelectRow`:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let itemSelected = currentData[row]

    if let currentField = currentField {
        currentField.text = itemSelected
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers mate, that worked. Sorry for not using the offical stamdard with capital letters etc. I am new to swift. Still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this test is being executed:

```
if (itemSelected == StadtArray[row]) {
```

...but, as you rightly say, the data actually being displayed in the picker view is *not* from StadtArray but from UntergrundArray. Thus, you select the fifth row and `row` is 4, but StadtArray has only four entries so index `4` is out of bounds; there is no such thing as StadtArray[4]. And so you crash.

You could fix this by arranging the tests in ascending order of array size, or by adding a size test on the array before speaking of `[row]`, but as rmaddy rightly says, the real problem is that your test for which source the `currentData` comes from is just a badly designed test.

What I personally would do is this. I would eliminate `currentData` and the five model arrays, and maintain my model data as a single *array of arrays*:

```
 let model = [["Asphalt", "Kunstrasen Sand", "Kunstrasen Granulat", "Rasen", "Tartan", " "], ["Norderstedt", "Hamburg", "Berlin", "München"], [ "2 vs 2", "3 vs 3", "4 vs 4", "5 vs 5"], ["1", "2", "3", "4"], ["Fußball", "Basketball"]]
```

Now I would maintain a single number representing the index into `model` of the current array:

```
 var currentModel : Int = 0
```

This makes things incredibly easy and direct! The number of components would be `model[currentModel].count`, and `titleForRow` would be `model[currentModel][row]` — and we could eliminate the `if/else` in `didSelect`, because `model[currentModel]` takes us *directly* into the correct model and so `model[currentModel][row]` works there too.

(Though actually, the title for the row *is* the data, so you could alternative just call `titleForRow` inside `didSelect`, couldn't you? And again there would be no danger of error.)